# How do I obtain all the information of the object of the "activeCat" that holds the state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, api, mapping

I am creating an app in which I am trying to establish an "activeCat" while it has been selected from the dropdown menu. I am able to switch the state of "activeCat" but it only hold the "nickName" of the cat(object).

here is my CatList component (dropdown)

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {Dropdown} from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class CatList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            cats: [],
            activeCat:''

        }
    }

    onClickHandler = event => {
        const activeCat = event.target.innerHTML;
        this.setState({ activeCat })
        console.log(activeCat)
        {this.state.cats.map((cat, index)=>{
            console.log(cat, index)
            if(index == this.state.activeCat){
                console.log(cat._id)
            return(
                <div >
               Hello
                </div>
            )
        }})}
      }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getCollection('All')
    }

    //get entire collection
    getCollection = (_Id) => {

        axios
            .get(`http://localhost:5000/api/kittys/getByUserId/${this.props.user._id}`)
            .then(res => {
                const cats = res.data
                this.setState({cats: cats})
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <p style={{display:"flex", justifyContent:"center"}}>Selected Cat: {this.state.activeCat}</p>
            <Dropdown
            style={{display:"flex", justifyContent:"center"}}
            className="cat-list">
                <Dropdown.Toggle variant="success" id="dropdown-basic">
                    My Cats
                </Dropdown.Toggle>
                <Dropdown.Menu>
                    {this
                        .state
                        .cats
                        .map((kitty, index) => {
                            return (
                                <div key={index}>
                                    <Dropdown.Item onClick={this.onClickHandler}>{kitty.nickName}</Dropdown.Item>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })}
                </Dropdown.Menu>
            </Dropdown>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Here is a picture of my console after clicking on the first item in the dropdown menu (Minnie)

[CONSOLE AFTER USING THE `ONCLICKHANDLER`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTOgH.png)

[here is a photo showing the dropdown and selected cat above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMiaU.png)

I would like to be able to display the Name of the ActiveCat above the dropdown menu, like I have, but I also want to have the rest of the cat's information available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of saving only the kitty name, you can save all kitty data passing it in your on click handler.

```
<Dropdown.Item onClick={() => this.onClickHandler(kitty)}>{kitty.nickName}</Dropdown.Item>
```

Then save it in the state.

```
onClickHandler = (kitty) => {
    this.setState({ activeCat: kitty })
}
```

Then you can access it.

```
<p style={{display:"flex", justifyContent:"center"}}>Selected Cat: {this.state.activeCat.name} {this.state.activeCat.gender}</p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked great. Now I am trying to pass that information to another component, so when the cat is clicked I can render a card with all their info. Could definitely use help, as I am new obviously.

Comment: For that I recommend you to use react-router-dom to navigate between components. Here is the documentation https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start. Hope it helps!